# Sql grouping with where

Tags: sql

I've got table like below:

```
Id  Name    Colours
1   Apple   Red
2   Apple   Green
3   Tomato  Red
4   Tomato  Red
5   Tomato  Red
6   Banna   Yellow
```

I need to group fruits by name and check if they are in one colour or they have various colours, so the result should look like:

```
Apple   Various
Tomato  Red
Banana  Yellow
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and `case`:

```
select name,
       (case when min(color) = max(color) then min(color)
             else 'Various'
        end) as color
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` to check the color variation :

```
select distinct name, (case when not exists (select 1 
                                             from table t1 
                                             where t1.name = t.name and
                                                   t1.Colours <> t.Colours) 
                            then Colours else 'Various' 
                        end) as Color
from table t;
```

Comment: Easy to understand and only checks for one matching row rather than scanning all the matches for the min and max values like the (currently) accepted answer does.

Comment: @Steve if you have an index on `color`, it won't scan everything for min/max, but I agree this solution is more verbose as not everyone can understand Gordon's code even though it's neat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Name, case when count(distinct Colours) > 1 Then 'Various' else Colours end as Colours
From mytab
group by Name
```

Comment: Column Colours is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: which db using. it will work in MySQL but not in Oracle. If you want oracle specific then will post that